# Java Code Cleanup: how can I know about the unused webservice in the project

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soap-client

I am new to web service, I got task to clean up unused soap web service. I have list of topdown and bottom up service. How can I know which services are unused and which ones are using. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't know just by looking at the server side code since you don't know what the clients are calling. The only way I can think is to check the access logs for the endpoints. You could then tell which ones are being used for sure, but if a client uses an endpoint very infrequently, that wouldn't be logged recently. You're really only guessing unless you have access to the client code that is using your webservices.

Comment: Thanks BrianPipa , can we get code cleaning of any specific service by just commenting out methods in SEI (service end point interface ).